# Printar conteudo em formato de lista com jquery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um codigo jquery ajax que me retorna dados de uma requisição, porem ele me retorna uma linha e depois apaga e joga a proxima em cima da anteriror, eu quero que ele me printe na tela 1 resultado em baixo de outro como uma lista, como posso fazer isso ?

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> chk </title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function enviar(){
    var bin = $("#bin_id").val();
    var linhaenviar = bin.split("\n");
    var index = 0;
    linhaenviar.forEach(function(value){

      setTimeout(

        function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: 'envio.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: "bin=" + value,
            success: function(resultado){
             $('#oi').html(resultado + "<br>");
          }
        })

      }, 10 * index);

    index = index + 1;

    })
  }
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<textarea name="bin" id="bin_id" rows="10" cols="40">
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="testar" onclick="enviar();"></input>
<br>
<div id="oi" name="oi">
<p></p>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar como a variável **resultado** está ? isto é, como o json está formulado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples amigo, assumindo que o seu `json (resultado)` retorne uma lista com dados, basta você usar a função `each` e a `prepend()`.

```
<textarea name="bin" id="bin_id" rows="10" cols="40">
</textarea>
<br>
<ul id="lista">
</ul>
```

Js:

```
success: function(resultado){
resultado.each(function(){
$("#lista").prepend("<li>" + resultado.dado + "</li>"); 
});
}
```

Caso o seu `json (resultado)` só retorne um dado e não uma lista você pode remover a função `each` e usar somente a `prepend()`.

```
success: function(resultado){
      $("#lista").prepend("<li>" + resultado.dado + "</li>"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A sua colocação na tela substitui sempre o anterior:

```
$('#oi').html(resultado + "<br>");
```

Em vez disso tem de acrescentar:

```
$('#oi').html($('#oi').html() + resultado + "<br>");
```

Assumindo que os dados recebidos estão da forma que se pretende apresentar.

Comment: Você salvou minha vida obrigado até que enfim terminei meu sistema de checagens :)

Comment: @BrunoLazarine Sem problema. Uma sugestão, se o `envio.php` é seu, melhor será enviar os dados todos de uma vez e processar do lado do servidor com php, para não fazer vários pedidos ajax desnecessários.

Comment: E que meu textarea tem uma lista de proxys e é nessessario executar uma chama curl para testar linha por linha e printar na tela entao usei jquery ajax para fazer o loop do codigo e o retorno dos resultados